# Animation of UI objects to play on death

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, animation

Basically, In my scene, underneath a GameObject called 'GameOverUI' I have some buttons and a Panel that covers the screen. I have made a simple animation where the panel's opacity (The alpha channel) increases. Do any of you know how to make it so that when the player dies, it enables GameOverUI and plays the animation for the panel once?

Edit: Forgot to mention, I know how to make it so that 'GameOverUI' is enabled, I just don't know how to make the animation play

Comment: How do you handle player's death? Do you reload the scene after the "You died" title?

Comment: Basically in my first question ever (on my account) shows part of the player script, but basically, I handle the player's health by using a float called 'currentHealth', which is the accumulative health of all limbs. When currentHealth reaches 0, I disable movement and make Time.timeScale = 0. I then make it enable a GameObjectCanvas, containing all the game over objects like buttons to restart and stuff. What my problem is that I have an animation component atached to the canvas with an animation making the panel's alpha channel go from 0 to 255 over time and make the buttons go on screen.

Comment: But it plays at the very start, when it is not enabled and never again, and what I want to happen is that it only plays once when the gameObject is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a solution with animations, then here you go:

Create a script for your `GameOverUI` gameObject. Really simple:

```
public class UIHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
   private void OnEnable()
   {
       //play "dead screen" animation
   }
}
```

Method `OnEnable()` is a `MonoBehavior` function, and will be called when you enable a GameObject by calling `myGameObject.SetActive(true);`.

However, I would recommend thinking about another solution. I usually leave `GameOverUI` always active and use it to manage its children via script. So I think it would be more elegant to write something like this:

```
public class UIHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
   public void PlayerDied()
   {
       //play "dead screen" animation
   }
}
```

The difference is, that instead of enabling and disabling the GameObject, you call a method. This way, you will be able to pass data (as function parameters) if you need to do so. For example, you can write to the screen, what caused the death. And further on, the GameObject will be able to manage its UI components for other purposes.

I hope it makes sense and I could be of your help!